# Please help me install my Brother DCP-7040 laser on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: printing

I installed the recommended printer for my brother DCP-7040 which is a 7050 and when I tried to run a test page, the printer just shows idle and nothing happens. I have gone to the brother site and downloaded the correct ppd driver. Brother describes how to install it but being the newbie that I am, I do not have the terminal skills to do this. I also tried unsuccessfully to use the cups driver. I just don't know what I am doing.

Thanks for any help I can get.

Joe

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=dcp7040_us_as) page lets you download a .deb file, that you can easily install on your system. Download it, go to the download folder and open it. 
The Ubuntu Software Center will show up and you'll be able to install the drivers, no terminal or complicated stuff to do :)

Be sure to have enabled partner repositories. If you don't, go to *Software & Updates* -> *Other Software* tab and enable *Canonical Partners* and *Canonical Partners (Source Code)*.

[image]

Comment: All of the files on the download page are .deb files which makes me wonder if it's necessary to enable Canonical Partners (Source Code) in Other Software. When installing a .deb file Ubuntu will try to install any missing dependency packages, so why would it be necessary to download source code too?

Comment: I suggested that not for this particular case, but for  future problems. Feel free to delete that part.
I apologize for my poor English.

Comment: Delete it yourself or ignore it if you prefer. I do code correction and code revision, but I don't devour other people's answers.

Comment: I think it's a good suggestion for newbies. If a moderator thinks it's a bad advice, he'll remove it. Thanks for the advice and the edit ^^

Comment: I tried to run the deb file and got the package is of bad quality. After ignoring and trying to install anyway, it looks as though it installs but when I run the printer installer I cannot find the 7040 driver.

Comment: With some effort I was able to open the cups web page local 631 and install a brother 1200 that showed up as recommended. I am able to print now. Thanks for the help. I am not sure why your suggestion did not work. I continue to learn and will not give up.

Comment: That's odd, but I'm glad you solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If the .deb file doesn't work on your system, or you need a PPD for installing in a different manner than CUPS/LPR, Brother has some directions on their site that can be partially automated. [https://help.brother-usa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/164936/~/how-to-create-a-brother-ppd-file-for-installation---linux](https://help.brother-usa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/164936/%7E/how-to-create-a-brother-ppd-file-for-installation---linux)

First you need to download the `BR-Script driver (Postscript language emulation)` for your printer model, this is actually under the Windows downloads, so change the operating system to "Windows" on the driver download page, and then click `Show All` under the `Drivers` section and then download the BR-Script file.

- Ironically the instructions that are ostensibly for Linux seem to be assuming you are running these steps on Windows.

If you are running on Linux you can use `unzip`, `mscompress` and the `msexpand` command provided by the latter to extract the `.exe` you downloaded (normally a self extracting zip if run on Windows) and then extract/expand the `.pp_` file using `msexpand yourprinter.pp_` and change the resulting file extension from `.pp` to `.ppd` and then you should be able to use it with the program that wants the PPD.